# How do I link .so shared library to .bc file?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, llvm

I am working on compiling code that references an external shared library for its functions using someone's modified LLVM code. However, I think I need to get the library linked prior to the optimization step with LLVM, because optimization is currently failing.

The code is as follows:

```
cat $VERIFY_FILE >> tmp.c

${CLANG} -O0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu $INCLUDE -emit-llvm -S -c tmp.c -o tmp_before_pass.bc || die "error: clang"

${OPT} -load $API_SO -${APIINSERT} tmp_before_pass.bc -o tmp_after_pass.bc || die "error: opt with CANAL"
```

tmp.c references an external library (specifically liboqs.so). But when running this, I get the following error:

```
opt: /usr/lib/llvm-3.4/include/llvm/IR/GlobalVariable.h:143: llvm::Constant* llvm::GlobalVariable::getInitializer(): Assertion 'hasInitializer && "GV doesn't have initializer!"' failed.
```

I think that it is failing because the external library containing all of the necessary functions and variables is not yet linked, and optimization fails. How could I link my .so library prior to optimization? Or is there any other way I could resolve this error? Upgrading to a newer version of llvm is not an option.

Comment: Add the external symbols you need to the .bc. Linking to a .bc is inherently impossible.

Comment: @arnt Thank you for your comment! Do you know how I could go about adding the symbols?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that part of my comment. Externals do have to be added, but the error is from a later point in the code, ie. it indicates that your module is right in this respect. At a guess, if you set a breakpoint at GlobalVariable.h line 143, you'll see a call stack that involves your $API_SO, and the code on the call stack will tell you about the problem.